# tranform Vue.config.js to vite.config.js build path

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I tried to change the buildpath from webpack to vite:

```js
publicPath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === “production”
        ? “./” // prod
        : “/”, // dev
```

I want to show the litte site it in a subdirectory of a domain. How can I realize this with the vite.config

Answer (score 9):

The equivalent Vite config option is [`base`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#base):

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
          ? './' // prod
          : '/', // dev
})
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vite-base-url-demo)

Comment: `Note that Vite doesn't load .env files by default as the files to load can only be determined after evaluating the Vite config`: https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config